# Как использовать rxjava для передачи сообщений?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

У меня есть поток который принимает посылки по UART

Мне надо, чтобы все подписчики получали эти посылки, т.е. что-то типо:

```
observable.send("Посылка");
```

Может я ещё плохо разобрался, но очень странно, что rxjava отправляет сообщение только один раз, при создании нового класса, например:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.from(new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
```

А как отправлять в него сообщения потом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить объект, на который можно подписаться и в который можно слать сообщения вам нужно использовать `Subject`.

[Пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/270023/):

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.onNext(1);
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
subject.onNext(2);
subject.onNext(3);
subject.onNext(4);
```

---

Также есть библиотека на его основе, дающая пару реализаций `Subject`-a, бывает полезной: [RxRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay)

Comment: Спасибо! Ещё вопрос, оно не позволяет мне создать public PublishSubject<boolean>, мне надо событие которое говорит о том, что статус девайса изменился (подключился/отключился)

Comment: @Fangog, наверное вам надо Boolean указывать

Comment: И ещё, мне надо принять только один пакет и далее отписаться, как я могу отписаться внутри onNext?

Comment: @Fangog, если я вас правильно понял, то создавайте подписчика с типом `Single` - так вы получите только один результат, после чего цепочка будет завершена.

Comment: Что-то типа `mySubject.asSingle().subscribe()`